# How to make a barplot with ggplot2 with 3 groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like these:

```
 "term" "Col_count" "JG_count" "Mix_count"
 "1" "activation of immune response" 79 38 84
 "2" "adaptive immune response" 79 41 80
 "3" "adaptive immune response2" 73 40 74
 "4" "biological adhesion" 158 115 195
 "5" "cell activation" 167 103 193
```

I have 3 groups (columns 2:4) 
and 1 category for each group.

I need to make a barplot with each of these category grouping the 3 groups like in this picture, using ggplot2: [image]

Can Someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to write some R-code already? Have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833375/how-to-group-data-and-then-draw-bar-chart-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need is `interaction` to create a combination variable of the three other variables that you can use as a grouping factor.

```
## First reshape the data
library(reshape2)
dat <- melt(dat)

## use the interaction between the variables to define the grouping
ggplot(dat, aes(term, value, fill=interaction(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Variables', palette='Spectral')
```

[image]

Comment: It Worked very Well. Thank you for your help.!

Comment: Let me ask you, If I wanted to make the plot ordering from bigger to smaller value, how can I do this?

Comment: in `ggplot2`, the ordering is determined by the `level`s of the factors, so, after the reshaping step, do `dat$variable <- factor(dat$variable, levels=c("JG_count", "Col_count", "Mix_count"))`.  Then proceed with plotting